# Delphi 2010/XE Out of Stack Space error on bds:/default.htm

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I get an 'Out of Stack Space' fatal error each time i try to run Delphi 2010/XE after i have cleaned/erease the temp IE/index files with a shell tool i have (SpeedCommander). Look like the tool makes a deep clean of the IE temp or index files that later hinder the opening of the Delphi Welcome Page (bds:/default.htm). To be able to run Delphi again i need to surf a great lot with IE or Firefox, may be to restablished the index files(???) - or reinstall Delphi. What's about it?  (OS: Windows SP3)

Comment: OS->Windows XP?  Version of IE Installed?

Comment: WINDOWS xp SP3 ie7. This problem of crashing Welcome Page is not new to Delphi (D2007). I have never seen a good working and definitive solution; neither why it happens when the IE TEMP/Index files are cleaned, destroyed or corrupted in some way. Ex:  http://bit.ly/gsiRI5 , http://bit.ly/hgK0hd , http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27575 (that 'fix' just do no work), http://bit.ly/dUrwLM etc. It also happens with DelphiXE.

Comment: Tried cleaning IE temp files with IE?

Comment: Thanks. I believe using IE itself to clean the temp files is what should be done at first. Other tolls or manual cleaning may somewhat corrupt some  some files or index used by Delphi. But how that could be possible? For my case, using IE to clean the temp file does not help.

Comment: The Delphi Welcome Page came back to life after installing IE8 (temp and index files were thus rebuilt). Morale: i will no more clean the temp/index files with third party tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found installing IE8 (i had IE7 with may be corrupted temp/index folders) Note: this solution works for me but others may find other ways to resolve the bug  - such as removing/cleaning the Temp files with IE.

Comment: what about this error coming up when you have IE9. does this cause the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same isse very annoying

I look into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin`

I found `EnableIDEUpdateCheck.reg`

I opened to see registry key `DELPHI XE 2 USE` 
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\` ....

I found into the registry

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Known IDE Packages
```

startpageide160.bpl ( this is the start page package used to load well come)

I suggest to avoid the start page loading, so i went into the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin
```

I renamend the bpl from `startpageide160.bpl` to `startpageide160_NOLOAD.bpl`

I clicked on the Delphi XE2 icon
it works fine ...

Answer (score 1):

Next time you get a problem like this, even thought it appears to be caused by an external problem (internet explorer dlls?), I would install MadExcept, and file a bug report at Embarcadero Quality Central, including the call stack from the mad-except bug report.

Comment: Tx. Similar bug has been reported as QC#80670 but no answer or explanation given by Embarcadero and status is closed! See: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80222

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate:

Bug on the Welcome Page that blocks Delphi 2010 launch (loading very very slow, 3 to 4 minutes, and even the compilation of draft!) If IE8 apparently poor indexing. This bug is also of a poor programming of the Delphi 2010 Welcome Page of which would (conditional) not consider the hypothesis of degradation of indexing files of IE8 (which gradually restores random navigation).

However the code of the Welcome page RADSTUDIO XE2 works with Delphi 2010 and is not bugged, so if you also have RAD Studio XE2, just copy the C: \ Program Files \ Embarcadero \ RAD Studio \ 9.0 \ WelcomePAge in place of C: \ Program Files \ Embarcadero \ RAD Studio \ 7.0 \ WelcomePage (by renaming for safety to keep the old file) and everything works normally

Comment: Peu de chance d'être compris en répondant en français... Few chances to be understood by answering in french.

Comment: In summary, according to Jean Louis, to fix WelcomePage in Delphi 2010  copy the one from XE2 that should be free from IE issues and still compatible with D2010

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to this is replace the welcome page in:

...\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\Welcomepage{language}\default.htm

Just replace it with a blank textfile with the same name and it's done....
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the WelcomePage160.bpl also worked for me fine. Just ignore the error message at the first start up of Delphi (after renaming the BPL) and make sure that Delphi will not try to find it in the future (apply NO at the error message and Delphi will not bother you again).

Thank you all mates.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 2007, in Win 7

Startup Error,

Using a variation of the above suggestions, I tried,

renamed the bpl from startpageide100.bpl to startpageide160.bpl,

Bingo! It works...

Then, with smart firewall (Norton) back on, hmmm, reloaded the original file (startpageide100.dbg)  in addition to (startpageide160.bpl).  Interesting, how browser, anti-virus updates, firewall updates, etc. interfere ...